# PyCharm pip install googlesearch giving error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping. I am using PyCharm IDE and on python 2.7 version.

I am getting the following error while installing the google search package in PyCharm.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google search (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for google search

I am not getting this error in other packages like `BeautifulSoup`, `Scrapy` and `Pandas`.

I tried upgrading version python 3.8/ 3.4 but the error persists.

Any pointers/ help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: have you try installing package manually ?  using "pip install package" command ?

Comment: yes, I have tried, but that too fails with same message

Answer (score 1):

Try installing

```
pip install google-search
```

Comment: I successfully installed google-search but the below commands donot work:

#from google-search import search

from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch
#from google import googlesearch

Answer (score 1):

The name of the package is google-search, so the following command will work :

```
pip install google-search
```

For next time, just googling the package will guide you to https://pypi.org/ where you can find the correct installation command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install google package:

```
pip install google
```

and then use googlesearch module, check the following reference:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/

Also you can use google-seach package directly. for this one try to install google-search package:

```
pip install google-search
```

Comment: I have successfully installed google and and google-search but not sure how to import the search package in that.

Comment: None of these lines work after installing google and google-search 

from google-search import search
from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch
from google import googlesearch

Comment: After install google package by " pip install google ", to import google search module, try: " from googlesearch import search "

following resource is very helpful: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/